# how to make a copy of an sqlalchemy object (data only)

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, copy

I get a db record as an sqlalchemy object and I need to consult the original values during some calculation process, so I need the original record till the end. However, the current code modifies the object as it goes and I don't want to refactor it too much at the moment.

How can I make a copy of the original data? The `deepcopy` seems to create a problem, as expected. I definitely prefer not to copy all the fields manually, as someone will forget to update this code when modifying the db object.

Answer (score 0):

You can have many options here to copy your object.Two of them which I can think of are :

- Using `__dict__` it will give the dictionary of the original sqlalchemy object and you can iterate through all the attributes using `.keys()` function which will give all the attributes.
- You can also use `inspect` module and `getmembers()` to get all the attributes defined and set the required attributes using `setattr()` method.

Comment: thanks. The internal structure of sqlalchemy object is more complex than just a bunch of attributes so using __dict__ is not as straightforward as with simple classes. Will look into inspect